# How can I conform NSSecureCoding in my Core Data entity class

Tags: core-data, nssecurecoding, transformable

I'm trying to use transformable with my entity class.
But I had to do with some transformer? ValueTransformer in Core Data.
I found some of them just making their own custom class, but for me I'm trying to use my Entity class generated by CoreData

It's my core data properties code

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension PersonEntity {

  @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<PersonEntity> {
    return NSFetchRequest<PersonEntity>(entityName: "PersonEntity")
  }

  @NSManaged public var gender: String?
  @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
  @NSManaged public var name: String?
  @NSManaged public var volunteered: Bool
  @NSManaged public var schedules: NSSet?
}

// MARK: Generated accessors for schedules
extension PersonEntity {

  @objc(addSchedulesObject:)
  @NSManaged public func addToSchedules(_ value: ScheduleEntity)

  @objc(removeSchedulesObject:)
  @NSManaged public func removeFromSchedules(_ value: ScheduleEntity)

  @objc(addSchedules:)
  @NSManaged public func addToSchedules(_ values: NSSet)

  @objc(removeSchedules:)
  @NSManaged public func removeFromSchedules(_ values: NSSet)

}

extension PersonEntity : Identifiable {

}
```

And It's my core data class

```
import CoreData

@objc(PersonEntity)
public class PersonEntity: NSManagedObject, NSSecureCoding {
  public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true
   
  enum Key: String {
    case id = "id"
    case name = "name"
    case gender = "gender"
    case volunteered = "volunteered"
  }
   
  init(id: UUID, name: String, gender: String, volunteered: Bool) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender
    self.volunteered = volunteered

// I'm getting Error here
// Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'NSManagedObject'
// Implements How?
    super.init(entity: , insertInto: )
  }
   
  public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encode(id, forKey: Key.id.rawValue)
    coder.encode(name, forKey: Key.name.rawValue)
    coder.encode(gender, forKey: Key.gender.rawValue)
    coder.encode(volunteered, forKey: Key.volunteered.rawValue)
  }
   
  required convenience public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    let decodedId = coder.decodeObject(forKey: Key.id.rawValue)
    let decodedName = coder.decodeObject(forKey: Key.name.rawValue)
    let decodedGender = coder.decodeObject(forKey: Key.gender.rawValue)
    let decodedVolunteered = coder.decodeObject(forKey: Key.volunteered.rawValue)

    self.init(id: decodedId as! UUID, name: decodedName as! String, gender: decodedGender as! String, volunteered: (decodedVolunteered != nil))
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to use transformable with your whole class? What is your goal here?

Comment: N:N relation, I try to put those person Entities inside 2d array in core data

Comment: Then create a proper relationship instead, Core Data supports many-to-many relationships

Comment: but i need to save 2d array in core data

Comment: Why do you need a 2d array, it is really hard to understand what you are trying to do and what the best way forward is. But you should _not_ store an entity as a transformable attribute.

Comment: i'm making schedule app, like part time by team. like [[person1, person2], [person 3,person4]] and these data are dynamic, it can be rearange by user.

Comment: so if it is impossible, should i just make multiple relation like firsttime, secondtime, thirdtime to have multiple person and store person in these relation attributes?

Comment: Create an entity Team? Team, Schedule, Person? Not sure what you have today but a third entity could be a way to handle this.